# Appending Single quotes to strings in C

Tags: c, c-strings

How do you concatenate single quotes to a character array in C ?

For example: I have a char array `FileName` with value `"hello world"`. I want to enclose hello world in single quotes like this: `"'hello world'"`. The function has been passed `FileName` so i can't initialize the array to the desired value. I'll have to concatenate the single quotes at the start and end of the string.

Comment: What did you try? Do you know about [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) ?

Comment: Or [strcat](http://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/standard_library_functions/string_h/strcat.php)?

Comment: strcat doesn't work. I get a segmentation fault when i try strcat.

Comment: First decide if your function is going to allocate memory for your new string (if yes, then find out how many bytes should be allocated), or maybe the code that calls your function will provide  an array for the result, or maybe you need to do that in-place (and have enough free space in the original array). Then use `sprintf`, or `strcat`, or just iterate over the string and copy characters. If we just write a code here, it won't help you to understand all these things.

Comment: `strcat` works fine. That segfault means you are trying to manipulate a `const` string. Show your code.

Comment: You can either a) allocate a new buffer and compose the new string into that buffer, or b) if you know that there's extra space in the buffer holding the original string, you can move the string by one byte and add the quotes. Question is, what is known about the size of the original buffer?

Comment: *"strcat doesn't work. I get a segmentation fault"*, this made me smile :). While `strcat` is one of the more dangerous C string functions, and you must be very careful how you use it, it certainly works fine: it does what it does reliably, and it can do what you want here easily and reliably, if only you use it as it should be used.

Comment: "strcat doesn't work. I get a segmentation fault when i try strcat" -- There's a huge difference between something not working and **misusing it**. If you tried it and got a segmentation fault, you should have posted your code so we could tell you what you did wrong, instead of just assuming that library functions that have been in use for decades don't work.

Comment: What i meant was that it's not giving proper results in THIS situation. I didn't know i had to be this specific. But sure, go ahead and give me a down vote. I've used it like this: strcat(FileName,"'"); Please enlighten me if there are other ways to use it.

Answer (score 1):

In order for this to work properly, the caller needs to pass you a string that has enough space for the two additional quotes. One way to make this work is to allocate a temporary buffer, construct your new string there, and copy it back to the original string, like this:

```
void add_quotes(char *s) {
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    char tmp[len+3];
    tmp[0] = '\'';
    strcpy(tmp+1, s);
    tmp[len+1] = '\'';
    tmp[len+2] = '\0';
    strcpy(s, tmp);
}
```

This allocates a temporary buffer in the automatic memory (i.e. on the stack). If your string `s` may be long, consider using dynamic memory allocation instead:

```
void add_quotes(char *s) {
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    char *tmp = malloc(len+3);
    tmp[0] = '\'';
    strcpy(tmp+1, s);
    tmp[len+1] = '\'';
    tmp[len+2] = '\0';
    strcpy(s, tmp);
    free(tmp);
}
```

Comment: that's not valid "C" - you can't declare an array with the length held in an expression.

Comment: @Alnitak Um, what? Why couldn't you use expression for VLA size?

Comment: Well, not originally.  I am a _little_ out of touch with the later updates to the C standard.  It seems that is legal C99.  It's not efficient, though - if the buffer is guaranteed long enough it would be simpler to `memmove` the string up by one byte in-place instead of using a temporary array.

Comment: e.g. `size_t len = strlen(s); memmove(s + 1, s, len); s[0] = s[++len] = '\''; s[++len] = '\0';`

Comment: @Alnitak VLA size is C99. I don't think that qualifies as "a little" in 2014 :-)  (although the last time I programmed in pure C was also 1999)

Comment: I learnt C around about 1987 - I mostly use C++ these days where VLAs are OK, but it's not easy keeping up with such major revisions of the standards.

Comment: @Alnitak Actually VLAs in C++ are available only as a GCC extension. They did not make it in C++98 and C++11; they were scheduled for C++14, but it looks like they are going to be out again.

Comment: "that's not valid "C" - you can't declare an array with the length held in an expression" -- One of the very worst things that one can do on technical sites is make erroneous "corrections" to things that are correct in the first place. Given dasblinkenlight's extraordinary C knowledge and experience, you should have assumed that he is correct until you had proven him wrong. "I am a little out of touch with the later updates to the C standard" -- you are in fact completely out of touch with changes made **15** years ago and familiar to all expert C programmers.

Comment: _Wow_.  Remember folks, “If you screw things up in tennis, it’s 15-love. If you screw up in [Stackoverflow], it’s your ass.”.  ***[From Here](http://www.predictem.com/boxing/sayings.php)***